# Update input field when the value of a select changes?

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

Update input field event `onchange`?

```
$A = array(A,B,C,D);

<select name="A" id="A" onchange="change_val()">
<?php 
foreach($A as $key=>$val){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key?><?php echo $val?"></option>
<?php }?>
 </select>
<input name="seleted_value" id="seleted_value" value="Hello first time" >
```

I want to write a `onchange` method `change_val()` that do this task:

if select A ( by default ) show value  'Hello first time' into input field `seleted_value`

else show value have selected into input field `seleted_value` AND `Disable this input field for read only.`

Anybody could guide me how to do this?

```
  if selected= A =>show 'Hello first time'
  if selected= B =>show 'B'
  if selected= C =>show 'C'
  if selected= D =>show 'D'
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and hasn't worked? Right now the question is just asking for somebody to write your code.

Comment: The value attribute of your option element could be shortened to

<?php echo $key . $val?>

You are also missing your ending " on that same value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
function change_val() { 
   var sel = document.getElementById('A'),
       lbl = document.getElementById('selected_value');

   lbl.disabled = (sel.selectedIndex !== 0);

   if(sel.selectedIndex === 0) {
      lbl.value = 'Hello first time';
   } else {
      lbl.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
   }
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobrelkin/UYeSL/2/)

Comment: <option value="0">A</option> NOT <option value="A">A</option>

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**

I suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. Then your code would look something like this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('select#A').change(function()
    {
        var this_value = $(this).val();

        if(this_value == 0)
        {
            //you made a typo (seleted), so i did this too on purpose
            $('input#seleted_value').val('Hello first time');
        }
        else
        {
            $('input#seleted_value').val(this_value);
            $('input#seleted_value').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not a supporter of using jQuery for such trivial tasks that can be done in straight JavaScript.

Comment: input#selected_value needs to be disabled not select#A and it should be disabled whether or not the onchange takes place.